# How to save numbers to mysql database as it is?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, number-formatting

I need to save numbers to database as it is please see the example.

- currently i save number as 22.5 and in database it is saved as 22.
- number in database is set as integer

  ```
  //sometimes $number can be "33.5" or "33" or "1" or "1.003"or "03"
  $sql = "INSERT INTO active (name, number) VALUES ('somename','$number')";
  ```

Comment: Change the column type in your database.

Comment: As far as I remember `INT` in MySql supports only whole numbers (without a dot). To keep the whole number `DOUBLE` or `REAL` can be used as types. In very rare cases it can even be `FLOAT`

Comment: Stuffing `22.5` into an `INT` column is like stuffing a corpse into a suitcase: something needs to be cut off.

Comment: use decimal column type

Comment: Also, `03` is the same number as `3`. If you need those to be different, you will have to store the representation of your number as a string (`VARCHAR`), not the number itself (which is okay for things like IDs where numbers are not actually numbers, but generally not something you want for proper numbers). And thirdly, Beware [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Can you post the table definition? Also, don't use SQL with variable inserts, use prepared statements and pass in your data as parameters, a lot less headaches and it will work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make your **number** column as **DECIMAL** data type, it will hold the decimal point with all numbers. Integer columns cannot hold decimal points.

If it is not your requirement, better use **VARCHAR** as data type (But **NOT RECOMENDED**).

Hope this helps.

Comment: `DECIMAL`, `FLOAT`, `REAL` or `DOUBLE PRECISION`, depending on what you need. `DECIMAL` for money, always; for most other uses `FLOAT` is fine.

Comment: Why `DECIMAL`? why not `float` or `real` or `double`? it depends on the requirments

Comment: **Never** use varchar to store decimal values. **Always** use the appropriate datatype!

Comment: Yes correct. Varchar because of **03** as mentioned in question

Comment: It's ok I change the column setting of number from **INT** to **VARCHAR** in database  and it's working fine now.

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin: `float` is ok if you never need more than 15 digits of precision. It's an *approximate* number vs. *exact* number like `decimal`

Comment: Can `float` support all required formats ? `$number can be "33.5" or "33" or "1" or "1.003"or "03"`

Comment: @user2767046: What is the meaning of that leading zero in `03`

Comment: @dnoeth, I am aware of that) Still was a valid question. I saw `float` used only once, and it's still not very clear to me why it was used. Probably because it used fixed 4 bytes of space.

Comment: @dnoeth I'm required to follow a stranded format that use this type of number strictly

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to check the structure of `active` table. From your question, I understand that various types of number values is going to be saved to `number` column. And I guess the type of `number` column in `active` table is numeric for int types. For example, INT or BIGINT or any other integer types.

Here is what I'm usually doing. Just use `varchar` for `number` field. It might not sound like professional. But it's very easy to use. By doing so, you won't have any problem with saving numeric value to the column. I have got an similar issue before while saving latitude and longitude value to the table. And php has got many functions to get actual float or int value from string. So this is an easy and simple way to fix.

Comment: You are right, storing decimal values as a varchar *is* unprofessional.

Comment: Actually there is not appropriate data type to save the value of multiple types of float, double and int. Using VARCHAR doesn't mean unprofessional way. It's even recommended way.

Comment: @Kenny: Recommended by *whom*?

Comment: @HoneyBadger Never say never. I had seen an inventory system that changed patterns, so you had old articles with ID like `0020` and new articles with ID like `000020`. Of course, these were never used for any arithmetic, so not really "numbers". "The type of the field should always be the most appropriate to store its values" is the closest thing I can come to a rule, if you will. I think only Sith deal in absolutes :)

Comment: @Amadan: Well, having article numbers like `0020` and `000020` is actually *not* showing professionalism :-) If those values are never use for any arithmetic they're just a series of digits and thus should be stored as a (var)char,

Comment: @dnoeth, Yes, I definitely agree with you

Comment: @dnoeth: Sure, it was definitely a bad idea to not extend the old schema and resume numbering, instead of starting over with more digits. Wasn't me who decided. Ever heard of legacy systems, and unwise managers? But if I need to stuff it into a database, it's a `VARCHAR`, not an `INT`.

Comment: @Amadan: Yep, bad idea :-) Of course I know (way too many) legacy systems: *has been grown with the company* or *over the years we had different consultants implementing it* and even more pointy-haired managers :-)

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest and reliable way to save the numbers/integers/floats to the database is to convert them to string and then storing them into the database.

**Note :** Your database column type should be of type string/text.

One of the advantage of this method is that you can overcome the limits of int/float/double.

```
$string_number = (string)$number;
$float_number = (float)$string_number;
```

Comment: As soon as you do some calculation you you're subject to *int/float/double limits* again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save number as 22.5 and in database. Then you need to change table column structure. Instead of **Integer/Int set to float** Then Next set length 10,2 
for information please check below screen short

[image]

Then you get proper output  **Happy Programming**